# .m2 folder in ubuntu not showing necessary folders

Tags: linux, windows, maven, ubuntu, repository

I have dual booted my laptop with windows and ubuntu. I want to use the windows maven project from ubuntu. I have installed maven in ubuntu `apt` repository. But when I check the `.m2` folder of ubuntu, there is only `org` folder and nothing else. Here is the screenshot of my `.m2` folder of windows and ubuntu. The first one is `.m2` of windows and second one of ubuntu.

Windows `.m2` repository

[image]

Ubuntu's `.m2` repository

[image]

Comment: it caches the things it downloads once, in ubuntu you might not have required other libraries

Comment: so you mean to say only `org` folder exists when maven is freshly installed?

Comment: no, when you try to compile something with maven, it downloads depedencies it needs to copmile

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because because of your user permissions. Have you tried listing all files in your .m2 using your "root" user?

Comment: what root user are you talking about? I mean how can we access the explorer using sudo

Comment: you can set the local repository on your settings.xml <localRespository>"ubunty .m2 location"</localRepository>. Once you do a mvn clean install - it will try to download all dependencies from your mirrors (settings.xml) and put them on the .m2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be an issueuntil you hit some maven phase or goal, i.e. you run the `mvn`command with some argument so it will resolve your dependencies and download them.

From the time this snapshot have been captured, it seems that only some artifacts **whom group names** begin with ***org*** have been downloaded; It might be:

- *org.apache.maven.plugins*
- *org.codehaus.groovy*
- *org.mongodb*
- ... or any atifact alike